# How to pass a variable to jQuery's .fadeOut()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that I want to pass to `.fadeOut()`.

Before we get to that, here's how I can pass an object to .click():

```
this.$title.click({story: this}, function (event){
    var story = event.data.story;
}
```

Simple enough.

Now I want to do something similar with `.fadeOut`:

```
this.$title.fadeOut("fast", {story: this}, function(){
    var story = ???
});
```

Which doesn't work. But you get the idea? How can I pass `this` into the anon function?

I'm looking for the cleanest solution. Barring that, I'm looking for the solution that's most in line with what I've done with `.click()`.

Thanks!

ASIDE: is there a cleaner way pass `this` into `.click()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is rather a question about JS than about jQuery; you can do it like that:

```
var story = this

this.$title.click(function () {
  /* story still available */
})

this.$title.fadeOut('fast', function () {
  /* same here */
})
```

Or something more fancy (this also preserves the content of `story` at the moment of assignment even if it gets overwritten in the upper scope later on):

```
this.$title.click((function (story) {
  return function () {
    /* story is available */
    /* this will be passed to $(...).click(...) */
  }
})(this))
```

Comment: I like your second suggestion, I think. Declaring local variables just to pass `this` around bothers me. I'll try it out.

Comment: @crowhill Yea you're right that is why I added it :P

Comment: Do you have an explanation for the (this) at the end of the function block? I've used that notation before, but I've never completely understood what it does. (the whole last line, I mean: "})(this))")

Comment: This is called an *IIFE* (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). You're just creating a function inline and calling it immediately with `this` as the argument. Better explanation here: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/ Or just google `js iife`.

Comment: That was hugely helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Though this is still the right answer to the question, I would like to point out that "this also preserves the content of story at the moment of assignment" is really important, depending on your context. For my purposes, I needed `this` to change and with the IIFE, that's not possible.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle so one can see what you're actually aiming to do?

Answer (score 2):

It seems [**fadeOut()**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) doesnt have an overload like [**click()**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) where you can pass `eventData`

> .click( [eventData ], handler )

Therefore, make a preserve `this` in a *closure* and use inside the function

```
var story = this;
this.$title.fadeOut("fast", function(){
    //story can be used here
});
```

Comment: No need for the named function, what makes `this` accessible in the callback is the closure `var story = this;`

Comment: @Jan, heh, very good point. Thanks for pointing out. Corrected my answer